# TFS automatically resets the test outcome

Tags: testing, tfs

I have created a test plan in the TFS Test hub, but while the test plan is being executed the Outcome field of the test cases are at some point (after approx. two weeks) automatically reset to "Active", so that I can no longer see which tests have already been executed and what was their outcome.

I do not know what I am doing wrong to cause these automatic resets. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make sure that no any other team members do the action: `Reset test to active`.

Besides, the outcome field will be automatically reset to "Active" **if all test runs are deleted**.

Based on your description the reset behavior appears after approx every two weeks. So please check if you have set the **Retention policy** to delete the test runs : `Days to keep manual test runs, results, and attachments`

(Go to `http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{Project}/_admin/_testmanagement` to set the test retention policy )

> You can configure this separately for manual and automated test runs.
>
> By default, for existing team projects, it is set to `Never delete`
>   any test runs. For newly created team projects, it defaults to keep 1
>   year of automated, as well as manual test runs.

So, if you want to keep the outcome field never to be reset, then just set to  `Never delete` or set the days as needed.

Refer to [Test result data retention with Team Foundation Server 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/10/08/test-result-data-retention-with-team-foundation-server-2015/) for details.

[image]

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot, saved my day!